# UITextField gives an empty string in ViewController in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

This might be simple for who had already done an app with Xamarin. I am working on a Xamarin Cross Platform app and have problem with the iOS.

I have a simple form with 5 text fields (UITextField). In the Main.storyboard, after adding these fields, I gave each of them a "Name" and it is linked to **FirstViewController.cs**. After I named them, the **FirstViewController.designer.cs** looks like this -

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;

namespace SampleApp.iOS
{
    [Register ("FirstViewController")]
    partial class FirstViewController
    {
        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UITextField custEmail { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UITextField custFirstName { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UITextField custLastName { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UITextField custLoginName { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UITextField custPassword { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UISegmentedControl custTitle { get; set; }

[Action ("UIButton54_TouchUpInside:")]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        partial void UIButton54_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender);

        void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
        {
            if (custEmail != null) {
                custEmail.Dispose ();
                custEmail = null;
            }
            if (custFirstName != null) {
                custFirstName.Dispose ();
                custFirstName = null;
            }
            if (custLastName != null) {
                custLastName.Dispose ();
                custLastName = null;
            }
            if (custLoginName != null) {
                custLoginName.Dispose ();
                custLoginName = null;
            }
            if (custPassword != null) {
                custPassword.Dispose ();
                custPassword = null;
            }
            if (custTitle != null) {
                custTitle.Dispose ();
                custTitle = null;
            }
        }

        }
    }
```

I also have a button **Add** in this screen which should capture text entered by user in each of these fields and call a method CreateCustomerAsync inside my PCL.

FirstViewController.cs looks like here

```
using System;

using UIKit;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SampleApp.iOS
{
    public partial class FirstViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public FirstViewController(IntPtr handle) : base("FirstViewController", null)
        {
            custLoginName = new UITextField();
            custFirstName = new UITextField();
            custLastName = new UITextField();
            custEmail = new UITextField();
            custPassword = new UITextField();
            custTitle = new UISegmentedControl();            
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.            
        }


        async partial void UIButton54_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            var customer = new Customer();

            var username = custLoginName.Text;
            var password = custPassword.Text;

            customer.firstName = custFirstName.Text;            
            customer.lastName = custLastName.Text;
            customer.email = custEmail.Text;
            customer.title = custTitle.SelectedSegment.ToString();

            CustomerResponse addCustResponse = await RESTWSManager.getInstance().CreateCustomerAsync(username, password, customer);

            Console.WriteLine("user name val", username);

            if (addCustResponse != null && addCustResponse.customer != null)
            {
                new UIAlertView("Xamarin POC", "Add Successful", null, "Ok").Show();
            }
            else {
                new UIAlertView("Hello iOS", "Customer Adding failed", null, "Ok").Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I enter a text in each of these fields and Tap "Add", the Button Action is triggered but the text field values show **EMPTY** - `" "`

Am not sure if I had missed anything in my complete procedure. It gives only empty for each text field. Could anyone please help.

[image: Error Screenshot with Empty String]

Comment: Why are you instantiating your fields in the constructor?  If they are defined in the designer this should not be necessary.

Comment: Agreeing with Jason. The runtime will create the instances for you. You do not need to create the instances manually.

Comment: yes, I did not know that. Have removed these from the constructor. The error was with 
public FirstViewController(IntPtr handle) : base("FirstViewController", null)

It should be 

public FirstViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)